# Subdirectories Show 404 Not Found on 13.10 web server

Tags: server, apt, apache2, mysql, php

I recently set up a web server on Ubuntu 13.10 and when I enter the external IP it works fine showing the index file of var/www/ but whenever I try to add a folder, say one called test, and I go to ext.ernal.ip.add/test it shows the 404 Not Found error.

Even when I try to access it using localhost/test I still get a 404 Not Found message and even when I try localhost/test/index.php I still get the same error.

In setting it up I installed Apache2, PHP5, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin (all with no errors).  Other than that I have not done anything else except add the following to apache2.conf:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

I'm new to setting up web servers and all this so if there is any other information needed for this question I will gladly edit the post ASAP, just let me know what is needed.

Again I'm wondering why I can't access folders within var/www/ over localhost or using the external IP when the folder has been created and an index file has been created inside of the folder.

Comment: Ensure that the directories and files you created are `chmod`/`chown`ed to the www-user.

Comment: Again I'm new to this so this is my guess on how to do that:  `sudo chmod 775 www-user /var/www/test` and `sudo chown www-user /var/www/test`?

Comment: @DigitalChris would the above comment work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428789/how-to-make-a-directory-apache-readable-on-ubuntu I only guessed at www-user, might be www-data, or apache or something else. Do `ls -l` in the `/var/www/` dir and see who the owner is there.

Comment: it says the following:
`drwxr-sr-x 2 matt matt 4069 Apr   9   09:11   test`
`-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 220  Apr   8   22:00   index.php`
@DigitalChris

Comment: nope that all that ls -l gave me.  My username on the computer is matt

Comment: Do `ls -l` in the `/var` dir and see the credentials for `www`

Comment: Wait a minute you said "when I enter the external IP it works fine showing the index file of var/www/" ... how is that possible if there is no index file?

Comment: In var this is what is show for www `drwxrwsr-x  3  777  matt 4096  apr   9  09:05 www`  and var/www/ has an index.php file.  Is that not the index file?

Comment: @DigitalChris is that what you were looking for?